# loop specific keys in dictionary to get values

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an associative array of workouts where the key is the workout name and its values are of an array of exercises.

I have a UITableView where it will contain each workout name and its exercises. My problem is getting the exercises for each workout and displaying it in its relating cell.

This is my code so far:

```
var workout = [String : [String] ]()

workout["Chest"] = ["Bench Press","Dumb bell incline", "Dumb bell flies", "flat Dumb bell Press"]
workout["Back"] = ["Deadlift","Lat Pulldowns", "Uni Lateral rows", "Dumb bell Row"]

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var keys = [String]()
    keys = Array(workout.keys)
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return keys.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WorkoutTableViewCell

    var keys = [String]()
    keys = Array(workout.keys)
    cell.workoutNameLabel.text = keys[indexPath.row]

    for value in workout[cell.workoutNameLabel.text!]!{

        print(value)

    }

    return cell
}
```

So in the first cell it will have a label for the workout name and another label underneath for a list of exercises concatenated into a single String.

For example:

The workout name is -  "Chest"
The exercises are -Bench Press,Dumb bell incline,Dumb bell flies, "flat Dumb bell Press

[image: Here is an image to help]

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking to create a string for that second label? Something like this?

```
let workoutKey = keys[indexPath.row]
cell.workoutDescLabel.text  workout[workoutKey]?.joinWithSeparator(", ")`?
```

Comment: Ah thank you Sir for your quick reply. This is what i was looking for!